# Howto stop phpMyAdmin server monitor?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I just activated the mysql monitoring in phpMyAdmin under the navigation tab 'Status->Monitor'. After starting it I cannot find any link to stop it :( Where do I stop mysql server monitoring again?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Pause monitor" link, located just under the line of buttons that contain "Monitor".